# Select source 'srcset' with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, web, attr, srcset

I would like to know how to select spcecific 'srcset' in my code using js. This is my actually not working js code :

```
var imgPath = $('.wp-post-image').attr('srcset');
$('.tax-product_tag .breadcrumbs').css('background', 'url(' + imgPath + ')');
```

And here is the HTML :

```
<img width="300" height="300" src="//agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-300x300.jpg 300w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-150x150.jpg 150w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-768x768.jpg 768w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-575x575.jpg 575w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-190x190.jpg 190w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-370x370.jpg 370w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-600x600.jpg 600w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-100x100.jpg 100w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-400x400.jpg 400w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-900x900.jpg 900w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-675x675.jpg 675w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-286x286.jpg 286w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-450x450.jpg 450w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-1080x1080.jpg 1080w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

The js code is working with 'src' attribute but this is selecting the 300x300 jpeg and i would like to get the orginal jpeg ( agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine.jpg )

Thks a lot for help, first time using stack overflow, sorry if I did mistakes with my question.

Comment: `srcset` contains a collection of URLs. You need to get the exact URL and set it.

Comment: exactly like @31piy said: you have a list of urls inside the attribute `srcset`, how do you expect the code to know which one it should use as the real `src`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img').each(function(){   //for loop all images
 var srcset=$(this).attr('srcset');  //attribut value
 var srcset_arr=srcset.split(', ');  //value to array
 for(var key in srcset_arr){         //loop array 
  if(key==srcset_arr.length-1){  //find last  element
     var orig_image=(srcset_arr[key]).split(' ')[0];  //first element of sub array
     console.log(orig_image);
  }

 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<img width="300" height="300" src="//agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-300x300.jpg 300w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-150x150.jpg 150w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-768x768.jpg 768w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-575x575.jpg 575w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-190x190.jpg 190w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-370x370.jpg 370w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-600x600.jpg 600w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-100x100.jpg 100w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-400x400.jpg 400w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-900x900.jpg 900w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-675x675.jpg 675w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-286x286.jpg 286w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-450x450.jpg 450w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine-1080x1080.jpg 1080w, //agothegoodlifestore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/la-mericaine.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the answer, will try to run it ASAP and let you know if it works.